# Почему выдает синтаксическую ошибку?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Есть код:

```
<?php
$limit = 2;
$query = "SELECT * FROM user";

$s = $pdo->prepare($query);
$s->execute();
$total_results = $s->rowCount();
$total_pages = ceil($total_results/$limit);

if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = 1;
} else{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}



$starting_limit = ($page-1)*$limit;
$show  = "SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $starting_limit, $limit";

$r = $pdo->prepare($show);
$r->execute();

while($res = $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  echo '<li class="all-tasks__li"><div class="comment-name">'.$res['username'].'</div>
        </li>';
}


for ($page=1; $page <= $total_pages ; $page++){
<a href="?page=$page" class="links">$page</a>

?>
```

Дело в том, что php выдает синтаксичускую ошибку на строке:

```
<a href="?page=$page" class="links">$page</a>
```

syntax error, unexpected '<'

Но я не пойму почему.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема?

Comment: спасибо вам большое! Не могли бы вы написать свой ответ в решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да потому что это PHP код - а ты в него HTML засовываешь... PHP в HTML существует, а вот наоборот - нет.

```
echo "<a href=\"?page=$page\" class=\"links\">$page</a>"
```

Comment: спасибо большое ещё раз!